# Windows 10 OS build not updating after general update

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am trying to instal WSL2 for windows 10, however, the [installation instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install) indicate the OS build needs to be 18917 or higher.

My Windows specs are:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Home
Version: 1909
Installed on: 4/27/2020
OS Build: 18363.778
```

Is this due to the fact I have Windows Home?
Is that the maximum possible build I can have?

Im already part of the Windows Insider program with the Slow setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this due to the fact I have Windows Home?

Windows 10 Home absolutely can run WSL 2 instances.  Your current installation is not running a supported build of Windows 10.  **You will either need to install the current Slow Ring build or wait until Windows 10 version 2004 is released.**

> Is that the maximum possible build I can have?

Your current installation has not received the proper Windows 10 Insider Preview build, the current Slow Ring build is not 18363.778, but 19041.208, which means enabling WSL 2 is not possible.  18363.778 isn’t even the current Windows 10 version 1909 build.

> I'm already part of the Windows Insider program with the Slow setting.

You might have indicated you wanted to receive the proper build, but it has not been installed, you typically must run Windows Update manually for that to happen.

> WSL 2 is only available in Windows 10 builds 18917 or higher

Source: [Installation Instructions for WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)

> I downloaded the Windows update installer and ran it manually, all I get now is: Thank you for installing the latest Windows version.

If you are attempting to use Media Creation Tool or the Upgrade Assistant then it has not been updated to install Windows 10 version 2004.  The quickest and simplest way to install the proper build is to download the current Slow Ring [Windows 10 Insider Preview ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced).

1. You will need to log into a Microsoft Account, which has become a member of the Windows Insider Preview program. If you do not have a Microsoft Account that satisfies this requirement, you will be unable to install the proper build on your machine.
2. You should select the current Slow Ring ISO:

[image]

3. There will be two ISOs, one for 32-bit another for 64-bit download the proper ISO that matches your system.

[image]

4. Once you have downloaded the file, mount the ISO from within Windows, and run the Setup.exe to migrate your current installation to the current Windows Insider Slow Ring build.  You should install all the available updates once you have installed build 19041.

Comment: I downloaded the Windows update installer and ran it manually, all I get now is: Thank you for installing the latest Windows version.

Comment: @johan855 - If you are attempting to use Media Creation Tool or the Upgrade Assistant then it has not been updated to install Windows 10 version 2004.

Comment: I am unable to provide a link to the ISO for one obvious reasons, the links are only valid for 24 hours, and I have no idea what language you want to installed.  You will have to select the same language you currently have installed otherwise, the installation process will indicate it's unable to migrate your personal files and installed applications, and a clean install is required.

Comment: I finally managed, somehow the installaton process was incomplete. After restarting several times and installing all updates, I was able to use my PC again but still the old build was there. I then downloaded the update assitant directly from windows again and run the update. This time the update process took longer but finally worked.